# distm in R leads to crash

Tags: r, distance, wgs84

So I have a pretty simple question regarding the size of my data. I am trying to calculate the distance between all sets points (WGS84) in a dataset (56000).

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-10/topics/distm
According to the documentation: distm(x,y,fun="") if missing, y is the same as x

`mydist<-distm(coordinates(mySpatialObject), fun="distHaversine")`

This led me to an Error that y was missing. So I figured I could easily work around this.

`distm(coordinates(WeedClim.plot),coordinates(WeedClim.plot), fun="distHaversine")`

This leads to not just R:Studio, but my entire computer freezing. I had to to a hard reset twice now and do not want to go through this again, because this is my dissertation and I am afraid of breaking something else in the project XD.

Any ideas/solutions? Is there a better function that gives me a distance matrix from a set of coordinates?

THANKS!

Comment: 56000^2 / 2  is 1,568,000,000 distances to calculate. That will take a lot of memory and a lot of time - how much memory does your computer have? Are you sure you need to calculate over 1 trillion distances to achieve your goal?

Comment: Well, I will need the distance matrix at some point. I don't need it for the distances right now, but the ultimate distancem atrix will be more complex (i.e. containing more than 2 values). So I will need to talk to the "geek squad" at work.

Comment: Thanks for following up. For reference, in R 1 million numeric values takes about 8 MB of memory (`print(object.size(x = runif(1e6)), units = "MB")`), so multiplying by 1000, 1 billion values would take about 8 GB, and 1 trillion values about 8 TB. If you want 2 values for each pair of 56,000 sites, that's about 3 Trillion values, so 24 TB of memory. AWS's highest memory option has 24TB of memory, but only available on a 3-year contract. I can't find the exact price, but the 12TB version is $802,575 for 3 years - you'd probably be looking at at least twice that for 24TB.

Comment: So, that's basically out of the question. You could do the computations on a cluster much more cost effectively and compile the results to a disk somewhere, but I still question how you'd be able to effectively use 24TB of results. You'd probably need to partition it and set up a database...

Comment: But I think the real solution will be to work backwards from your goal and find a smaller scale solution. If you can bin the points beforehand, and get down to, say 20,0000 distances you want in pairs, we're down to 400 million records - still big, but more doable. Maybe you can cluster points together, maybe you can do your calculations on a subset of data, most of statistics is set up to deal with cases where you *don't* have complete data, so find a way to use  less data.